# Python @property (setter method) that is restricted to setting data only in the __init__ method

Tags: python, oop, properties, pandas, setter

I would like to setup an object that imports some raw_data during the initialization phase of the object (i.e. during the `__init__()` method). However I would like to make it read only from that point on. I was thinking of using a setter property `self.raw_data` with the following logic:

```
@raw_data.setter
def raw_data(self, dataframe):
    <IF calling from __init__>?
        self.__raw_data = df
```

Is there a way for the setter method to know if it is being called from within `__init__`?
Blocking all other attempts to change the data.

Comment: Try [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576527-freeze-make-any-object-immutable/).

Comment: Why not just set `self.__raw_data` directly?

Comment: I would like to be able to set it within the __init__() method but nowhere else to effectively turn the variable .__raw_data into a read only attribute. I would like to guarantee it's state so I don't inadvertently assign to __raw_data later on.

Comment: I should be a little clearer. I agree ``self.__raw_data`` fixes the external accessibility by making the raw_data private. However I would like to protect it from other internal methods operating on the data in the same class.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get is to only allow to set `self._raw_data` if it hasn't been set, like in this example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, dataframe):
        self._raw_data = dataframe

    @property
    def raw_data(self):
         return getattr(self, '_raw_data', None)

    @raw_data.setter
    def raw_data(self, dataframe):
        if hasattr(self, '_raw_data'):
            raise AttributeError, "Attribute is read-only")
        self._raw_data = dataframe
```

Which makes the setter mostly useless, so you'd get the same result with less code skipping it (which will make the property read-only):

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, dataframe):
        self._raw_data = dataframe

    @property
    def raw_data(self):
         return self._raw_data
```

But beware that none of these solutions will prevent you to directly set `_raw_data`.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing you do in the `raw_data` setter is going to stop direct assignment to `__raw_data`. I would recommend not defining a setter and using `__raw_data` for initialization. This will block writes to `raw_data`, but not `__raw_data`.

If you want stricter enforcement, then by design, you don't have many options. One option is to write your class in C or Cython. The other option is easier, but it has awkward side effects. That option is to subclass an immutable built-in type, such as `tuple`, and create pre-initialized instances with `__new__` instead of mutating them into an initialized state with `__init__`:

```
class Immutable(tuple):
    __slots__ = [] # Prevents creation of instance __dict__
    def __new__(cls, *whatever_args):
        attribute1 = compute_it_however()
        attribute2 = likewise()
        return super(cls, Immutable).__new__(cls, attribute1, attribute2)
    @property
    def attribute1(self):
        return self[0]
    @property
    def attribute2(self):
        return self[1]
```

This makes your objects immutable, but the awkward side effect is that your objects are now tuples.

Comment: Yeah - Thanks. I might just write a simple script that parses the python source checking for any `__raw_data=` assignments outside of the __init__ method. Then all I need is an Immutable pandas DataFrame?

Comment: @sanguineturtle: Maybe. I'm not familiar with Pandas.